# How to fix issues with Django registration template importation/referencing

Tags: python, django, directory

I have recently started a blog using django from Corey Schaeffer's tutorial. I am stuck at part 6: User Registration, the feedback says template does not exist at users/register.html at line 19.

I have attempted to send the directory in settings to the absolute location of my templates, but it keeps responding with the same feedback.

I must be incorrectly referencing in my register.html or settings. Or even worse, a clerical/technical error!

My settings file

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'lzjtwkmz)f5nmj+@^vmiu^2rk+!24f1if72aq81+ny=wiiwn+g'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['C:/Users/sabay/django_project2/blog/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

my register.html file

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

I expect the output to result in webpage of the register page however the actual result leads to me a 'TemplateDoesNotExist at /register/'.

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry if the code text is horrendous to look at, this is my first time using stackover flow.

Comment: Try this `'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`

Comment: I applied the 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')], it doesn't seem to change the result of TemplateDoesNotExist at /register/.

Comment: One thing did change with the results though, the feedback at the template loader post mortem has changed from  django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\sabay\django_project2\blog\templates\users\register.html (Source does not exist)                               to                                                                              django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\sabay\django_project2\templates\users\register.html (Source does not exist)                                     Could the my referencing between the /blog/ and /template/ be incorrect?

Comment: check the output of `print(BASE_DIR)`

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan I have tested the print(BASE_DIR) in the command prompt and the command prompt returns  C:\Users\sabay\django_project2. Is this ideal?

Comment: Is your `templates` directory is inside `django_project2` dir?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the / in front of register, 'register/' instead of '/register/'